# How Do I Get the Starting Location of the Client Area in a Form, Relative to the Form's Top-Left Corner?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I create a Form, Size=(300,300),
then its `.ClientRectangle` property returns {**X=0,Y=0**,Width=292,Height=266}

From the Rectangle that we receive, it seems that we get the `Size` of the Client Area, but not the `Location` inwhich it starts relative to the form's Top-Left corner(above th title bar and border)..

The X and Y values are always **0,0**,
yet we know that there is an offset between the Form's top-left corner, and its Client Area..
(because there is the Title Bar, and form Border)
So how can I get the actual starting point for it?

Going over Control's properties, I couldn't find one,
and as written above, the X,Y part of the `.ClientRectangle` property always returns 0,0..

The reason I ask this, is because If you want to use the `Control.DrawToBitmap()` method,
then you need to supply it with a Bitmap object with some size.
If you create a Bitmap in the size of `Form.Size`, then you can capture the whole form.

It will look like this:

[image]

Yet if you want to capture only the client area of the form,
then you can create a Bitmap object with size=Form.ClientRectangle,
but then you need to know at which point the client rectangle starts..
or else, your capture will look like this:

[image]

As can be seen, it's indeed in the size of the client area, but it doesn't start at the right location..

So when wanting to capture only the Client Area of the form, we need to know where the client area starts, relative to the Form's real starting point
(the top-left point, at which the border corner is, right above the title bar)

Comment: It's relative to form, do you need its coordinates relative to desktop?

Comment: *how can I get the actual starting point* `.Location`

Comment: **Reza Aghaei:** I need it relative to the form's top left point. By "the form's top left point" I mean the top-left point where the TitleBar and Border corner are..

Comment: **Plutonix:** That is not my question.. I am not talking about the Form's location relative to the screnn, I am talking about the Form's Client Area's location relative to the Form's top-left corner..

Comment: You probably want to use `.Location` to get screen position, you may need to factor in multiple screens though... `ClientRectangle` give you the *inside* of the form (so it's always 0,0 at top-left). The width/height adjustments are due to the windows 'frame' (title bar and border). [This is useful for the different options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684725/winforms-position-and-dimension-properties).

Comment: `we know that the Client Area in a Form starts in bigger values than 0` no, we do not know that.  The client area is the internal space usable for controls etc.  Some values from `SystemInformation` like `BorderSize` and `CaptionHeight` might help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @spaceman When you want to mention someone in comments, you can use @ before the username, this way a the user will be notified.

Comment: @spaceman: You made the question very complicated. It's not really anything to do with starting location, as that implies it changes.... You should have mentioned client area offset relative to the form (with border) or something likethat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for that:

```
 // -8, -30 at my workstation
 // so 30 is a size of caption and top border
 //     8 is a left border size
 Point leftTopShift = PointToClient(this.Location);
```